# A callback function is called multiple times in event loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to understand the behavior of the code below. I tried to register a callback function `trampoline` to be called in an event loop using `asyncio` module. The `trampoline` got itself is called multiple times, which I am sure why that happened please. My expectation was the callback `trampoline` will call itself only once later after `0.5` seconds?

```
import asyncio
import datetime

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def print_date():
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

def trampoline(name: str = "") -> None:
    print("name:", end=" ")
    print_date()
    loop.call_later(0.5, trampoline, name)

loop.call_soon(trampoline())
loop.call_later(8, loop.stop)
loop.run_forever()
```

**Output**: I also have an exception, which also I am not sure about:

```
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:04.335313
Exception in callback None()
handle: <Handle>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:04.850481
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:05.363303
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:05.872649
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:06.383004
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:06.898766
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:07.413907
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:07.915795
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:08.428609
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:08.939604
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:09.454111
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:09.966438
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:10.470832
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:10.981675
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:11.496746
name: 2022-11-11 16:29:12.011841

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: "My expectation was the callback trampoline will call itself only once later after 0.5 seconds". Yes, and what happens when that second call to `trampoline` takes place?

Comment: I guess you don‘t want to call trampoline() but instead pass the function?

Comment: @tfeldmann so you're saying it should just be `loop.call_soon(trampoline)` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `trampoline` schedules a callback to itself when called.

That means that `trampoline` will be called after 0.5 seconds, rescheduling again a callback to itself for 0.5 seconds later

To have it only called once, you should remove `.call_later` from inside `trampoline` and move it outside:

```
...
def trampoline(name: str = "") -> None:
    print("name:", end=" ")
    print_date()

loop.call_later(0.5, trampoline)
...
```

The exception is due to calling `.call_soon` with `trampoline()` (the return value: `None`) instead of `trampoline` (the function itself)

Comment: Thank you. Why it does stop though after some calls? In the code, `loop.run_forever()` was used, so should not `trampoline()` run forever?

Comment: I guess it's because we call `loop.call_later(8, loop.stop)` that will stop the event loop.